# csv to 2D double array

Tags: java, arrays, csv, 2d

I'm trying to convert a csv spreadsheet into a double 2D array. I have managed to convert the csv into a 2D string array. I am now trying to convert that into a double.  I am getting a `NumberFormatException` I believe this is because when I try to `Double.parseDouble,` it keeps reading the column header which is a string. It may also be the commas in my csv? Not sure what my next steps are.

```
public class Filetester {
    private String myArray [][] = new String [50][]

public Filetester(String filename) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    String delimiter = ",";
    int count = 0;
    s.nextLine();
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        count++;
        String line = s.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(line);
        String[] arrayAsString = line.split("\\s*" + delimiter + "\\s*";
        myArray[count] = arrayAsString;
        double[] arrayAsDouble = new double [arrayAsString.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayAsString.length; i++) {
            arrayAsDouble[i] = Double.parseDouble(arrayAsString[i].replaceAll(",", "");
       }
 }
```

}

my csv looks like this

```
A, B, C, D 
1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
13.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
```

Comment: *I believe this is because when I try to Double.parseDouble, it keeps reading the column header* - then read the first line outside your main loop and ignore it. You may also need to use the String.trim() method to remove leading/trailing spaces before parsing the string as a s Double.

Comment: OK.  So your code won't compile because you haven't declared `delimiter`.  But I can also see that your code doesn't skip the header line.  So your first theory is correct.  (But you don't **keep** reading it.  You only read it once ... and then the application fails because you attempt to parse a column name as a `double`.)

Comment: How can I skip the first column header line for my double array? I tried to set i =1 but that won't work because the loop reads it one time so it does not go further than 1. I fixed my code to declare delimiter.

Comment: What do you think the `nextLine()` method does?

Comment: @camickr Would it be correct? to include an extra s.nextLine() outside of my loop?

Comment: That is what my original comment suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've fixed my code and removed the commas, however I am still getting a NumberFormatException when I try to Double.parseDouble

Comment: `count++; String line = s.nextLine(); if (count < 2) { continue; } /* the rest of your code */`. When splitting the line use: `String[] arrayAsString = line.split("\\s*" + delimiter + "\\s*");` so to remove any possible whitespaces before or after the comma.

Comment: I am getting a NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0"

Comment: Is that particular string actually in a file line? There are no delimiters (other than whitespace) between values. Your example indicates that commas (,) are used as delimiter within the CSV file.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I used Double.parseDouble(arrayAsString[i].replaceAll(",", ""); to remove the commas

Comment: Don't use that. If the line is properly split, you won't have any commas or whitespaces with the values contained within the `arrayAsString[]` array. Unless of course there is specific data in this file youhaven't shown us.

Comment: String[] arrayAsString = line.split("\\s*" + delimiter + "\\s*"); doesn't seem to work I get the NumberFormatException: For input string "1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0"

Comment: There is no such exception named `NumberFormatException` available for running that particular line of code. You will get that exception when you try to parse a numerical string which contains an alpha character into a any one of the Java numerical data type objects like `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, etc.

Comment: *I've fixed my code and removed the commas* - why? How do you expect the String.split() to work? There is no need to remove the commas. I suggested you need to remove the `spaces`. There is no need for a complex regex. Just split on the commas, I gave you a simple suggestion in my first comment to remove the excess spaces. Did you try it? Or, the other option is to remove the spaces from the file. Try both suggestions so you understand both solutions.

Comment: @Kevin, I see you accepted a complex solution to such a simple problem. You really should understand the simple suggestions provided here and understand why they fix the problem. Copying other people code doesn't help you learn to debug problems. The first step in problem solving is to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few suggestions I think might help you out here a little but keep in mind, I have no idea what your ultimate goal is with regards to your specific application.

What I see is a class (**Filetester**) that contains an instance member String array variable named `myArray[][]`. I don't understand why you want this to be a *String Array* when you are actually seeking to achieve a **double[][]** data type array. I would suggest you declare this a double[][] type array that you can gain access to via a [Getter method](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/java-getters-and-setters/) once the **Filetester** class has been [instantiated](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-instantiation-in-java-definition-example.html). And, don't initialize this variable, right now you have no idea whatsoever how much data may be contained within the supplied CSV file in the class Contructor. Do this when the **Filetester** class is actually instantiated:

```
public class Filetester {

    private double[][] csvFileDoubles;
    
    // Contructor
    public Filetester(String filename) {

    }

    // Getter Method
    public double[][] getCSVFileDoubles() {
        return csvFileDoubles;
    }
}
```

As it stands, a **Filetester** object can only be instantiated if a string representing the path and file name of the CSV file to process is provided within its Constructor for the **Filetester** class and for now this is good enough but I don't think it's a good idea to slam all your code into that Constructor. Keep things simple and readable in your constructor(s). Call a method from the constructor to carry out any tasks, for example:

```
public class Filetester {

    private double[][] csvFileDoubles;  // Default is null.
    
    // Contructor
    public Filetester(String filename) {
        this.csvFileDoubles = getDoublesFromCSV(filename, ",");
    }
    
    public double[][] getCSVFileDoubles() {
        return csvFileDoubles;
    }

    /* Returns a 2D double type Array (double[][]) from the data contained
       within the supplied CSV data file. It is expected that you also supply
       the delimiter used within that supplied CSV file. Any CSV file supplied
       to this method is also expected to contain a Column Names Header Line
       as the very first line of the file.                               */
    private double[][] getDoublesFromCSV(String csvFilePath, String delimiter) {

    }

}
```

You'll notice a few things here. First the instance member array variable `csvFileDoubles` is getting initialized and filled by the `getDoublesFromCSV()` method and this only happens when **Filetester** is instantiated.

Secondly, both the `csvFileDoubles` array variable and the `getDoublesFromCSV()` method are declared as ***private*** which means that the only way to get the contents of the `csvFileDoubles` array is to call the `getCSVFileDoubles()` Getter method which is declared as ***public*** and, the `getDoublesFromCSV()` method can only be called through the **Filetester** class Constructor.

The **getDoublesFromCSV()** method is the actual work-horse for the **Filetester** class (so far). It is what retrieves the CSV data you want and returns it in a **double** data type array. Later on you will most likely have other methods within this class that will do just as much work. I suggest you read all the comments within the method. Here is how the entire **Filetester** class might look like:

```
public class Filetester {

    private double[][] csvFileDoubles;  // Default is null.
    
    // Contructor
    public Filetester(String filename) {
        this.csvFileDoubles = getDoublesFromCSV(filename, ",");
    }
    
    public double[][] getCSVFileDoubles() {
        return csvFileDoubles;
    }

    /* Returns a 2D double type Array (double[][]) from the data contained
       within the supplied CSV data file. It is expected that you also supply
       the delimiter used within that supplied CSV file. Any CSV file supplied
       to this method is also expected to contain a Column Names Header Line. */
    private double[][] getDoublesFromCSV(String csvFilePath, String delimiter) {
        /* A list collection can grow dynamically so it really 
           doesn't matter how many data lines are contained
           within the CSV file. You don't need to worry about
           it.                                              */
        java.util.List<Double[]> doublesList= new java.util.ArrayList<>(); 
        
        // 'Try With Resources' use here so to auto-close reader when done.
        try (java.util.Scanner reader = new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File(csvFilePath))) {
            /* Read the header line before processing the data lines.
               In this case, we want to ignore it.                 */
            String line = reader.nextLine();  

            // Read through all the other CSV file data lines...
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = reader.nextLine();   // Sequencially, read in a line
                if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    // If for some reason the line read is blank then ignore it.
                    continue;
                }
                // Split the read line into columnar parts based on the supplied delimiter.
                String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s*" + delimiter + "\\s*");
                /* Convert the numerical string value in each column of 
                   the read in line into an element of a 'Double' data 
                   type array so to prep for addition to the List.                */
                Double[] linePartsAsDouble = new Double[lineParts.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < lineParts.length; i++) {
                    /* Confirm the column data is actually a String representation
                       of a numerical value so as to prevent the possibility of a
                       'NumberFormatException'. We use the String#matches() method
                       for this with a small Regular Expression (regex). If confir-
                       mation fails then (for this demo) we're going to make it -1.0.
                       Use whatever you like here. The regex used ensures that a string
                       representation of either a signed or unsigned integer or 
                       floating point numerical value was supplied.             */
                    if (!lineParts[i].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                        lineParts[i] = "-1.0";
                    }
                    linePartsAsDouble[i] = Double.parseDouble(lineParts[i]);
                }
                // Add the created Double[] data type array into the List/
                doublesList.add(linePartsAsDouble);
                
                // Go and read in next line (if there is one)...
            }
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // Display the 'FileNotFoundException' and returns null.
            System.err.println("getDoublesFromCSV() Method Error!");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        
        /* All is good so far so convert List<Double[]> to a primitive
           double[][] type array and return it.                     */
        double[][] dblArray = new double[doublesList.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < doublesList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < doublesList.get(i).length; j++) {
                // Streams (Java 8+) is used here to convert from Double to double.
                dblArray[i] = java.util.stream.Stream.of(doublesList.get(i))
                                .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
            }
        }
        return dblArray;  
    }
}
```

And, here is how you might use this **Filetester** class:

```
public class DemoApp {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Create an instance of Filetester. Supply the full
           path and file name to the Constructor. If you just
           supply the file name as shown below then that file 
           must be contained within the root of your app's 
           Project directory.                             */
        Filetester test = new Filetester("DoublesData.csv");
        
        /* call the Filetester.getCSVFileDoubles() getter
           method to retrieve the generated 2D double[][]
           array.                                       */           
        double[][] dblArray = test.getCSVFileDoubles();
        
        // Display the contents of the 2D Array (dblArray[][])
        for (int i = 0; i < dblArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(dblArray[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

With the example floating point file data you provided, if you create a project named **DemoApp** and have these two above classes in it and the sample data placed into a file named **DoublesData.csv** located within the root directory of your project then you see the following result within your console window when the application is run:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
[13.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: If you don't expect wrong values it's best performant execute Double.parseDouble and catch the NumberFormatException (that only takes time for each wrong value), than check all times with a regex

Comment: This is of course true and noticeable performance could possibly be observed when processing **very large** CSV data files.